# How to draw restricted cubic spline of complex survey?

Tags: r, splines

I am analyzing complex survey data and I want to draw restricted cubic spline with OR. I have learnt how to draw restricted cubic spline with logistics regression, but Y-axis of the figure is probability of outcome event=1 and I want OR to be Y-axis. I attached my code in R below, hoping to get your help. Any tips will help and thank you!

Code:

```
mydata<-read_dta("D:/data1115.dta")

design<-svydesign(data=data1115, id=~id, strata=~strata, weights=~weightage, nest=TRUE)

svy.fit<-svyglm(outcome ~ age + gender + drugs + educations + income, family=quasibinomial(link="logit"), design = design)

**y<-predict(svy.fit)

y<-as.numeric(y)

y<-exp(y)/(1+exp(y))**

mydata$y<-y   #(probability of outcome event=1)

model.spline<-lm(mydata$y ~ rcs(mydata$age))

rcs(mydata$age,n=4)

ggplot(mydata, aes(age, y))+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method = lm,formula = y ~ rcs(x,4))
```

How should I replace the bold part of code to get the OR value?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "draw" a cubic spline?  Would that be some sort of graph?  What graph?  Or maybe some kind of sampling procedure?  Why are you applying ordinary least squares but calling it "logistic regression"?  What role is this `model.spline` object supposed to play in your analysis?

Comment: Thank you for concerning. I will answer your question point by point. 
1. I mean "get" or "output" when I used the word "draw".
2. Yes!  
3. I don't know whether my answer is what you want, but I want to get a fitting line graph. 4. No!  5. logistic regression is to build a prediction model and ordinary least squares is to fit the line graph of predicted value (now it's probability, but I want OR) and age. 6. To build restricted spline regression (Knots) .